# HTML File Loses Input Values when Printed or Exported

Tags: javascript, html, obiee

new to HTML and JS so please excuse me (and tell me) if I'm being stupid...

I have a form I have created a partially completed form on OBIEE using html and JS with drop-downs and User Input boxes for employees to complete the remaining details.

I initially had a problem that when the form was printed or exported to a .mht file to send to us, the previously input data had disappeared, this wasn't too much of an issue because the workaround was to just export the page first and then complete it.

However, I have now made some updates to the form and started playing around with JS - nothing to clever just formatting todays date in DD/MM/YYYY format. The problem with this is that again when the file is exported/printed to .mht I lose the content of the input box

So my question is, does anybody know how I can ensure the content of my input boxes remain when the form is printed/exported to .mht?

Answer (score 0):

Through much trial and error I finally found an answer. In the end I eventually changed the way I approached the situation and replaced the values within the input box as a text value by storing the input to a variable and then inputting the variable. Which looked a little something like this;

html:

```
    <input class="simpleCart_input" id="DateAuthorised" type="date" maxlength = "10" style="text-align: center"></span>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="result()">
```

JS:

```
function result()
{
//replace dynamic date with dynamic date value
var data = $("#DateAuthorised").val();
$("#DateAuthorised").replaceWith('<span id="changedText">'+data+'</span>') 
}
```